# PHP: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE When calling variables

Tags: php

Why would I be getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE` on this line?

`$fieldLabel = '<label for=".'$fieldNameStripped'.">.'$fieldName'.</label>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your line should be like this

```
$fieldLabel = '<label for="' . $fieldNameStripped . '">' . $fieldName . '</label>';
```

Comment: -1. You're not answering the question as to *why* a parse error occurs.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're not using PHP properly - syntax errors:

```
$fieldLabel = '<label for="' . $fieldNameStripped . '">' . $fieldName . '</label>';
                           ^^^^                  ^^^
```

You had the concatenation operators INSIDE the strings, so you weren't concatenating at all.

Try

```
$fieldlabel = <<<EOL
<label for="$fieldNameStripped">$fieldName</label>
EOL;
```

HEREDOCs make such things trivial, and far far easier to read. With a modern syntax highlighting editor, the variables will even stand out for you.

You could also prepare your string like this:
$fieldLabel = "{$field->name}";

Here the double quotes surround the outer string mean that PHP will parse variables inside it.  You however then have to escape double quotes.  I've changed the $fieldName variable to show how you would wrap the variable in {} brackets for items such as object properties (I tend to use them even for regular variables inside strings just because I feel it's better practice to be consistant).

Answer (score 1):

```
$fieldLabel = '<label for="'.$fieldNameStripped.'">'.$fieldName.'</label>';
```

Is how you should do it.

In what you have done, there are two problems:

1. When using `.` for concatenation, you should confirm that the strings to both sides of `.` should be `"properly closed"`.
2. Also, say if you have `$var = 1;` and you `echo '$var';` you don't get `1`. you get `$var` as output.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fieldLabel = '<label for="'.$fieldNameStripped.'">'.$fieldName.'</label>';
```